# Why am I able to print the sizeof variables even though I have not initialised them in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, declaration, sizeof

I am trying to understand when exactly  a variable get memory in C when declared inside main function . I found a similar question [When does memory gets allocated for a variable in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693126/when-does-memory-gets-allocated-for-a-variable-in-c) here. It mentions that there is no hard and fast rule when memory will be allocated. But I am trying to understand my case specifically . I just declared some variable of different types but did not initialise any one of them. I just tried to print the sizeof those variable and I was able to print it. My question is whether memory is already allocated  as I am able to print the size of the variable which I declared ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int x;
int *y;
float a;
float *b;
double a1;
double *b1;
char c;
char *c1;


printf("sizeof of x = %d \n",sizeof(x));
printf("size of *x = %d \n",sizeof(*y));
printf("sizeof of a = %d \n" ,sizeof(a));
printf("sizeof of *b = %d \n" ,sizeof(*b));
printf("sizeof of a1 = %d \n" ,sizeof(a1));
printf("sizeof of *b1 = %d \n" ,sizeof(*b1));
printf("sizeof of c = %d \n" ,sizeof(c));
printf("sizeof of *c = %d \n" ,sizeof(*c));    
}

Output:
sizeof of x = 4 
size of *x = 4 
sizeof of a = 4 
sizeof of *b = 4 
sizeof of a1 = 8 
sizeof of *b1 = 8 
sizeof of c = 1 
sizeof of *c = 1
```

I have some follow up questions as well. Why there is a difference in the sizeof pointer variable based upon data type ? At the end, any pointer varaible will contain an address which is an integer.

Comment: Because it’s known at compile time

Comment: You don't print the size of any pointer in your program. `y` is  the pointer, `*y` is the data the ponter pints to.

Comment: Because the size is known whether or not there is an allocation. You can also do `sizeof(int)` which isn't a variable but a type. Note that "any pointer variable will contain an address which is an integer" is incorrect. All computer data is bits, but a pointer is not an integer nor `int` and your `%d` is undefined behaviour. Please use `%zu` for type `size_t`.

Answer (score 3):

From the C Standard (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 2 The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which
> may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is
> determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer.
> **If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the
> result is an integer constant.**

So in your program all expressions with the `sizeof` operator (your code does not have a declaration of a variable length array) are not evaluated and their result values are determined at compile time.

The compiler uses an expression in the `sizeof` operator to determine the type of the expression.

You could even write for example

```
printf("sizeof of ++x = %zu \n",sizeof(++x));
```

or

```
printf("sizeof of ++x + ++*y = %zu \n",sizeof( ++x + ++*y));
```

Neither object is changed in these calls of `printf` with expressions with the `sizeof` operator. The memory that occupied by the objects is not accessed..

Pay attention that you have to use the conversion specifier `%zu` instead of `%d` in calls of printf like

```
printf("sizeof of x = %zu \n",sizeof(x));
```

Otherwise using an invalid conversion specifier can invoke undefined behavior.

Also instead of using expressions in the `sizeof` operator you may use type specifiers.

```
printf("sizeof of x = %zu \n",sizeof int );
```

If you would declare a variable length array then the `sizeof` operator is evaluated at run-time (that is it is required to determine the number of elements in the array that can be done only at run-time) each time the control achieves an expression with the `sizeof` operator with a variable length array.

Consider this simple demonstration program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    for ( size_t n = 1; n < 6; ++n )
    {
        int a[n];
 
        printf( "sizeof( a ) = %zu\n", sizeof( a ) );
    }
}
```

Its output might look like

```
sizeof( a ) = 4
sizeof( a ) = 8
sizeof( a ) = 12
sizeof( a ) = 16
sizeof( a ) = 20
```

As for the memory allocation then for each object with automatic storage duration memory is allocated when the object is declared.